# Angularjs: Cannot display array items using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using AngularJs to retrieve the data from ASP.Net Controller.
The Json data is retrieved from the server, but can't figure out why cannot display array items when using the ng-repeat:

```js
  var app = angular.module('Appp', []);
        app.controller('metadataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

       
            $scope.lookupItems = {};
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/home/listvalues?listid=3' }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.lookupItems = response;
                console.log($scope.lookupItems);
            },
               function (error) { alert("error"); });

           // console.log($scope.listItems);

        });
```

```html
   <form name="myForm" ng-controller="metadataCtrl" class="my-form">
   
          <div ng-repeat="item in lookupItems">
              {{$index}}
              {{item.ListValueID}}
        </div>
   </form>
```

The Json Retrieved from the server:

```js
[{"ListValueID":13,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"Important","LanguageValues":{"ar":"مهم","en":"Important"}},"ListCategory":{"ListID":4,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"","LanguageValues":{"ar":"","en":""}}},"Parent":0},
 
 {"ListValueID":14,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"Less Importance","LanguageValues":{"ar":"أقل أهمية","en":"Less Importance"}},"ListCategory":{"ListID":4,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"","LanguageValues":{"ar":"","en":""}}},"Parent":0},
 
 
 {"ListValueID":15,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"Very Important","LanguageValues":{"ar":"كثير الأهمية","en":"Very Important"}},"ListCategory":{"ListID":4,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"","LanguageValues":{"ar":"","en":""}}},"Parent":0}]
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle for this

Comment: Are you sure that you're setting `ng-app` correctly in your view? Looking at it right now it should theoretically work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue (assuming that your app and controller are constructed and referenced properly) is that the object returned from the promise contains a `.data` property which actually holds your JSON data.

Try this:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/home/listvalues?listid=3' })
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.lookupItems = response.data;
        console.log($scope.lookupItems);
    },
    function (error) { 
        alert("error"); 
    });
```

Comment: Next time use the network tab of your browser developer tools to see what data is being brought back.  Would have saved you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to wrap your app with ng-app:

```js
var app = angular.module('Appp', []);
        app.controller('metadataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

       
            $scope.lookupItems = {};
            
 $scope.lookupItems = [{"ListValueID":13,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"Important","LanguageValues":{"ar":"مهم","en":"Important"}},"ListCategory":{"ListID":4,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"","LanguageValues":{"ar":"","en":""}}},"Parent":0},
 
 {"ListValueID":14,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"Less Importance","LanguageValues":{"ar":"أقل أهمية","en":"Less Importance"}},"ListCategory":{"ListID":4,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"","LanguageValues":{"ar":"","en":""}}},"Parent":0},
 
 {"ListValueID":15,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"Very Important","LanguageValues":{"ar":"كثير الأهمية","en":"Very Important"}},"ListCategory":{"ListID":4,"Translation":{"TranslationID":0,"Value":"","LanguageValues":{"ar":"","en":""}}},"Parent":0}];
                console.log($scope.lookupItems);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Appp">
   <form name="myForm" ng-controller="metadataCtrl" class="my-form">
   
          <div ng-repeat="item in lookupItems">
              {{$index}}
              {{item.ListValueID}}
        </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Germando, but i have specified the module on the body. This is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably misspelled Appp.  Make sure your module definition in your javascript:

```
 var app = angular.module('App', []);  //Changed to App from Appp
```

matches your app declaration in your html

```
<div ng-app="App">
...controller declaration...
...body.....
</div>
```